# Can System.Web.dll be deployed stand alone with a WinForms application targeting .NET 4 Client profile?

Tags: c#, deployment

I just added functionality to my WinForms application that is being used by ~25 client machines and it now needs to reference System.Web which isn't in the Client Profile.

I'm trying to figure out if I need to install .NET 4 full framework on each machine or if it's possible to get around that.

Can I somehow include System.Web and *not* switch my target framework away from Client profile?

Comment: What do you need from system web in a winforms app?

Comment: I am using an embedded [HTML editor](http://windowsclient.net/articles/htmleditor.aspx#_Toc43806131)

Comment: Yes, you do have to deploy the full profile.  The license does not include rights to redistribute portions of any of the .NET profiles.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply include System.Web and any other DLL's that this app depends on in the app's working directory. You can try setting the property "CopyLocal" equal to "True" in the assembly reference properties to make this a bit easier.

You can also GAC them, but if the .net profile is updated to the full version it may cause problems.

Comment: It turns out that if I set CopyLocal to True in VS, it just flips it back automatically but it was worth a shot...